# To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

Пытаюсь установить material ui. Версия реакта `17.0.2`
выдает ошибку

```
added 43 packages, and audited 2033 packages in 17s

10 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

команда fix  не дает результата. Команда `npm audit`
выдает

```
# npm audit report

browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1747
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
  react-dev-utils  >=6.0.0-next.03604a46
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
    Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
    node_modules/react-scripts

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@1.1.5, which is a breaking change
node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    watchpack-chokidar2  *
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2
      watchpack  1.7.2 - 1.7.5
      Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack-chokidar2
      node_modules/watchpack
        webpack  4.44.0 - 4.46.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of watchpack
        node_modules/webpack
          react-scripts  >=0.10.0-alpha.328cb32e
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
          Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
          node_modules/react-scripts
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.11.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server
      @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  0.3.1 - 0.5.0-rc.6
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
      node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin

10 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

не могу понять, что с этим делать?

Comment: ничего не делать

Comment: Если интересно, есть такой пост (на английском) https://overreacted.io/npm-audit-broken-by-design/

Comment: дело в том, что когда я подключаю какие то элементы из material ui выдает ошибку `Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/material/TextField' `

Comment: `To address all issues (including breaking changes), run: npm audit fix --force` никак не связано с проблемой, о который вы пишете в комментарии